# Insert data from a php table to my mysql database

Tags: php

I would like to ask for support to be able to insert the data I bring into a table and insert it into a table in my mysql database.

[image]

I have a button that I want to click on to save the data in a mysql table.

How do I pass the data that is in the table and send it to the database?

Can I do it using AJAX?

Comment: Share the code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can save using AJAX. One possible approach:

1. When a user clicks save, run a loop in javascript to gather the fields of each row into an object, and add it to an array; a structure like:

```
var table_data = [
    {field1:value1, field2:value2, field3: value3...}, // one of these for every row in the table
]
```

*fieldX* would be the names of your column headers, and *valueX* would be the values of those fields.

2. Using ajax, post the data to a server-side script. An example using jQuery:

```
$ajax.({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'script.php',
    data : { 'submit_data' : table_data } 
});
```

3. On the server in a file called script.php, receive the POST'ed data, and then run a loop over the data to save each row to the table. Here's a sparse example, using PHP and mysqli:

```
$mysqli = database_connection();
$data = $_POST['submit_data']; //sanitize this!

foreach($data as $row){
    $mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO data_table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES($row['field1'], $row['field2'], $row['field3'])" );
}
```

Bear in mind the above is very unsafe for a production environment; at a minimum, you should use prepared statements and parameter binding to insert the data: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

I hope this gets you going. GL!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I extract the data from the table? I use datatable plugin.
I would like to extract the data from the datatable and send it through an array using ajax. Could you help me please.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with datatable to know whether it has functionality to convert the table data into an array, but, using jquery, you can do something like:

```
var table_rows = array();
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
   
   var row = array();
   $(this).find('td').each(function(){
      row.push( $(this).text() );
   });
  table_rows.push(row);
})
```

Bear in mind the above is an array of arrays, and not an array of objects that contain the field names